# MySQL / MariaDB: InnoDB: Fatal - how to fix it?

Tags: mysql, innodb

it is friday but no weekend yet. :( My colleague is on vacation and I myself am not a MySQL Pro.

So this morning today our pages stopped working and I am trying to fix for hours now but couldn't solve it myself.

So, baseline error is:

"Status: "InnoDB: Fatal: Trying to access page number 62087 in space 0 space name /var/lib/mysql/db/ibdata1, which is outside the tablespace bounds. Byte offset 0, len 16384 i/o type 10.Please check that the configuration matches the InnoDB system tablespace location (ibdata files)""

I did find a quite similar problem here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/183862/trying-to-solve-outside-tablespace-bounds-mysql-error-but-recovering-table-wi

Sadly there is no solution provided.

The command "mysqldump" from the post above won't work anyway, as the whole service is not starting up.

I recreated the DB status from yesterday using snapper -> that is why I absolutely have no clue why it does not work now. Tried the timestamp from Wednesday - same issue.

Configuration reads:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql/db
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

innodb_data_home_dir = /var/lib/mysql/db
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

# include all files from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d


innodb_force_recovery=4
```

Moving / renaming the original ibdata1 did not solve anything. The thought was that maybe letting the system recreate the file would solve the problem.

Any input on this is highly appreciated.

*I do not much care about data loss as long as the service will be running again, which has the highest priority right now.*

Thanks a lot

James

Comment: It might help if we could see the files in the `includedir`.

Comment: If you are willing to lose all data, all logins, etc, uninstall mysql and make sure its data is removed.  Then reinstall.  (Yes this is overkill.)  For a more careful approach, let's see the log files.